# Search for markers in a markercluster group Leaflet-MarkerCluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.markercluster

I am using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to cluster my markers in my [Mapbox Map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.0.1/). The markers are to be populated using a `json` file. All I need is a search feature which can popup the requisite marker based on search string. I got to know about [Leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search), but am unable to integrate it with my code. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate through your layer group (like your Marker Cluster Group), e.g. using [`eachLayer(fn)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#layergroup-eachlayer), test against the marker attributes, and if you find your target marker, get the map to zoom and/or pan to it using markercluster [`zoomToShowLayer(targetMarker)`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-group-methods) method.