# Add Leaflet Search through a Feature Group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Similar to [Search for markers in a markercluster group Leaflet-MarkerCluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631492/search-for-markers-in-a-markercluster-group-leaflet-markercluster)

But i am using a [Control group](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) ontop of [Marker Cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) so they will be displayed upon a radio button click.

```js
var map = L.map("map"),

parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup(options), // Could be any other Layer Group type.
  
// arrayOfMarkers refers to layers to be added under the parent group as sub group feature
    
mySubGroup = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup, arrayOfMarkers);

parentGroup.addTo( map );
mySubGroup.addTo( map );
```

I am attempting to implement [Leaflet Search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) - but as per the documentation says it requires a `group layer` of markers as the second parameter for it work. Trouble is using `L.featureGroup.subGroup` requires an array of markers.

Attempted to iterate through `mySubGroup` at run time to get the layers of markers using [Leaflet eachLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-eachlayer) but this will duplicate the amount of markers i have on the map for the search to work.

```js
var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup().addTo( this.map );

forEach( mySubGroup, layers => {
    layers.eachLayer( function (layer ) {
        console.log ( layer );

        markersLayer.addLayer( layer );

    })
});

   map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({layer: markersLayer}) );
```

Comment: call in the eachLayer function `layers.removeLayer(layer)`

Comment: @FalkeDesign this will remove my `mySubGroup`  clusters and replace it with single point markers

Comment: Then don't add the layergroup to the map `var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup()` else you will always duplicate the markers. But I don't know if this works with the SearchControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue - though it's quite inefficient. If you can find a more elegant solution to avoid duplication then feel free to contribute it as an answer!

```js
 var title = layer.options.title;

// iterate through the cluster points
forEach( mySubGroup, layers => {
    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        var title = layer.options.title; // match the search title to marker title

         marker = new L.Circle(new L.LatLng(layer.getLatLng().lat,layer.getLatLng().lng),
            {radius: 0, title: title, fill: 'red', fillOpacity: 0, opacity: 0 }); // Create an invisible L circle marker for each cluseter marker 


        markersLayer.addLayer(marker);

    })
});
```

You then add the markersLayer to the Leaflet Search